# pybind11 both python 2.7 and 3.6

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I'm trying to work with pybind11 and create my `library.so` for both python2.7 and python3.6. I'm using the cmake package to use pybind11 but can implement my own as well.

As far as I can see, I need to specify the python version I use when I install pybind. I need to specify that so `add_pybind11_module` would know with which python to link etc. In addition, I can create the so on my own using g++ and create both so's.

In addition, I need to create the so's in different folders because their names are the same.

I guess there is already an existing solution for this problem. Is there a built in support in pybind11 or is someone did a cmake plugin for it?

Thank you

Comment: Er, if you specifically want to know how to do that **with cmake**, it might be a good idea to say it explicitly and add a cmake tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your extension twice and generate two `.so` files. You can do it with simple bash script, it would be something like that:

```
# build module for 3.6 
mkdir -p build-python-3.6
(cd build-python-3.6 ; cmake .. -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=3.6 ; make )

# build module for 2.7
mkdir -p build-python-2.7
(cd build-python-2.7 ; cmake .. -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7 ; make )
```

pybind11 includes python version in library name by default, therefore you should be able to have them in the same folder (e.g. `my_library.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`). While it might work I would suggest you to write a `setup.py` and let `setuptools` to place your library in appropriate place.